# Converting multi dimensional array into hash of hashes in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am having a multi dimensional array like

```
arr =[['a','1','2','3'],['b','3','4','5'],['c','12','33','12'],['a','3','5','3']]
```

and I want this into hash of hash like

```
hash = {
  'a'=> {
    '1'=> {'2'=> '3'},
    '3'=> {'5'=> '3'}
  },
  'b'=> {
    '3'=> {'4'=> '5'}
  },
  'c'=> {
    '12'=> {'33'=> '12'}
  } 
}
```

I have tried using merge but I am not sure on assigning

I had tried with 3 elements in array like

```
pairs = [['a','1','2'],['b','2','3']]
BLOCK_META_DATA = {}
new_hash = {}
pairs.each do |x|
  x.each_slice(3) do |a,b,c|
    new_hash[b] = c
    if BLOCK_META_DATA[a].nil?
        BLOCK_META_DATA[a] = new_hash
    else
        BLOCK_META_DATA.merge!(a => new_hash)
    end
    new_hash.clear
  end
end
```

But when size of array increases and common key value comes, it is getting confused

Comment: *"Assume everything are string..."* then change your example since none of those are `String`. Right now your `Hash` is not actually vaild since `1:` cannot be a key and `:"1"` is awful. Also if everything is a `String` syntax would be `{"a" => { "1" => { "2" =>"3"}}}`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Updated the problem

Comment: It's unfortunate you didn't make the correction before the downvotes piled up. When you give an example, always ensure that: 1) each input is a valid Ruby object (no `a` when you mean `"a"`, no `...` or "etc."; 2) make the example as brief as possible; 3) assign a variable to each input value (here `arr = [...]`, as you have done); and 4) show the desired result as a valid Ruby object. (No variables need be assigned to outputs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Here is one. I use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a hash to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
arr =[%w| a 1 2 3 |, %w| b 3 4 5 |, %w| c 12 33 12 |, %w| a 3 5 3 |]
  #=> [["a", "1", "2", "3"], ["b", "3", "4", "5"],
  #    ["c", "12", "33", "12"], ["a", "3", "5", "3"]]

arr.map { |a,b,c,d| { a => { b => { c => d } } } }.
    each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g) { |_k,o,v| o.merge(v) } } 
  #=> {"a"=>{"1"=>{"2"=>"3"}, "3"=>{"5"=>"3"}},
  #    "b"=>{"3"=>{"4"=>"5"}},
  #    "c"=>{"12"=>{"33"=>"12"}}}
```

See the doc for `Hash#update` for a description of the three keys in the block that computes the hash value for keys present in both hashes being merged. The first, `_k`, is the common key. I wrote that beginning with an underscore (you'll often see just `_`) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.

The first step is

```
arr.map { |a,b,c,d| { a => { b => { c => d } } } }
  #=> [{"a"=>{"1"=>{"2"=>"3"}}},
  #    {"b"=>{"3"=>{"4"=>"5"}}},
  #    {"c"=>{"12"=>{"33"=>"12"}}},
  #    {"a"=>{"3"=>{"5"=>"3"}}}]
```

This array of four hashes is then converted to a single hash (represented by the block variable `h`, which is initially empty), using `update`.

Comment: Thanks #Cary Swoveland